# Uncaught ReferenceError: href is not defined

Tags: javascript, outbound, gtag.js

I have found this code on github to automatically track outgoing URLs with gtag.js.

```
<script>
    var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
      gtag('event', 'click', {
        'event_category': 'outbound',
        'event_label': url,
        'transport_type': 'beacon',
        'event_callback': function(){document.location = href;}
      });
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('a[href^="http"]:not([href*="//' + location.host + '"])').on('click', 
            function(e) {
                trackOutboundLink($(this).attr("href")); 
                return true;
            });
    });
    </script>
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: href is not defined

When I put `'event_callback': function(){document.location = url;}` it would work, but then the link is opened twice in a new window and in the same tab.

I am a dummy with this stuff... could you put me in the right direction?

Comment: `.location = url;`, `return false` - but this will break the navigation when `gtag` doesn't execute the `event_callback` (for whatever reason)

Comment: Where is your `href` variable defined and what you expect it to be/happen?

Comment: `document.location = href` ...where is `href` supposed to come from here? As far as I can see, it isn't defined - which is exactly what the error message is telling you. You have never created a variable with that name or given it a value. Please explain what this line of code was intended to do, and where you want to get the value of `href` from.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer to your questions... as I said, I just found the code on github.

Answer (score 1):

OK - this is working as supposed now:

```
<script>
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
  gtag('event', 'click', {
    'event_category': 'outbound',
    'event_label': url,
    'transport_type': 'beacon',
    'event_callback': function(){window.open(url);}
  });
}
</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('a[href^="http"]:not([href*="//' + location.host + '"])').on('click', 
        function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            trackOutboundLink($(this).attr("href")); 
            return true;
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this may be it would help

```js
<script>
    var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
      gtag('event', 'click', {
        'event_category': 'outbound',
        'event_label': url,
        'transport_type': 'beacon',
        'event_callback': function(){window.open(url);}
      });
    }
    </script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('a[href^="http"]:not([href*="//' + location.host + '"])').on('click', 
            function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                trackOutboundLink($(this).attr("href")); 
                return true;
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: _"When I put `'event_callback': function(){document.location = url;}` it would work, but then the link is opened twice in a new window and in the same tab."_

Comment: @shanu thank you. that works fine. any way to open the link in a new window?

Comment: use this window.open(url); in place of  document.location = url;